# How to return back Alt+Tab behavior from showing application windows to showing application icons?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, window-manager, application-switcher

Something strange happened. And now, when I'm using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between windows, I see my running application windows over application icons.

So now I see the following when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>:

[image: Now]

And I want to return back good old behavior (otherwise I'm worried to get mental trauma):

[image: Before]

P.S. Sorry for low-quality images. I can't make screenshots during <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I somehow got both application switches enabled:

1. Gnome
2. Compiz

All I need is to install CompizCongig Settings Manager and just disable Compiz application switcher.

Comment: In my case compiz turns it on again after reboot. Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: @PuercoPop yeah, I had the same problem. If you just disable Compiz with checkbox it won't disable it forever unfortunately :( The workaround I came up with is to go to hotkeys section and just disable Alt+Tab shortcut.